# 'zu' missing in "Ich komme laufen"?

Tags: grammar-identification

Learning German on Duolingo, I stumbled on the sentence

> Kommst du auch laufen?

Which means:

> Are you also coming to run?

And I cannot understand the grammar here.

- I thought that if I want to say "I come to run", I use the zu construction. Kommst is not a modal verb, so it should have the 'zu'?

  > "Kommst du auch zu laufen?"

  - Maybe it is really a separable verb "laufenkommen"?
  - Or it is just an annoying exception?

What I'm missing?

Comment: The same goes for French, too, but verbs of motion (*I don't know the accurate grammatical term for this*) such as "come" and "go" are followed immediately by an infinitive verb without any preposition in between, when used in the sense "come/go to do ..." in English. Incidentally, the purpose-denoting "to" translates as "um ... zu ...", not "zu ..." in German.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb **kommen** is a "half modal". It's sometimes used as it was a modal verb, with a bare infinitive:

> Kommst du laufen?
>
> Wir gehen schwimmen.
>
> Sie sieht ihn stürzen.

There are a lot more of such verbs, most about moving to practice another action, or perception.

---

> <s>Kommst du auch zu laufen?</s>

This is ungrammatical. You may actually hear it in some some dialects but it means

*Are you having time for running?*

That is because to make it grammatical, one inserts a *dazu*

> Kommst du auch **dazu**, dass du läufst?
>
> Kommst du auch **dazu**, zu laufen?

and *dazu kommen* means *Are you having time for it?*. This is tricky. The verb *dazukommen* in contrary means *coming to the group*. The difference is all in the stress. See *'umfahren* vs *um'fahren*.

---

You could write

> Kommst du auch zum Laufen?

instead, making *laufen* a noun. This phrase may mean **both** depending on the stress, and that's why the modal phrase is often preferred.

Comment: I should have written "Kommst du auch, um zu laufen." I won't edit for clarity.

Comment: Do you have some sources about these half modals? Like Wikipedia or some grammar books. It's good to know when to use um..zu and where not.

Comment: For starters, those http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/VollHilfModal/Andere.html But they are all **with** *zu*.

Comment: https://www.sprachzentrum.de/blog/2011/02/24/lassen-brauchen-horen-sehen-helfen/

Comment: https://deutschegrammatik20.de/spezielle-verben/modalverben/die-modalverben-einfuehrung/

Comment: I think, 'kommst du auch zum Laufen' may have a a further, slightly different meaning: 'kommst du auch zu dem Laufen, das wir beide als festen wöchentlichen Programmpunkt in unserem Terminkalender stehen haben?' Cf. 'kommst du (heute) auch zum Yoga / zum Französisch(kurs) / ...?' In most cases, I would understand 'kommst du auch laufen?' as 'kommst du (heute) auch mit laufen?'

Comment: For me 'half modal' might be misleading, especially considering that there are 'Modalitätsverben' (drohen zu, scheinen zu ...). I understand your quotation marks as announcing a metaphoric mode of expression. What you mean may be the fact that form a syntactical point of view in German there are more verbs than just modals combining with a simple infinitive, like verbs of perception, verbs of 'Ortsveränderung', 'teaching/learning'  and some others.

Answer (score 0):

In general and formally you would say
`Kommst Du auch, um zu laufen?`
or 
`Kommst Du auch zum Laufen?` (in the latter, Laufen would be an event where people meet, not just running)

To my understanding, your example denotes a typical linguistic simplification of the day-to-day language

Answer (score 0):

You‘ve got it almost right, the correct sentence would be „Kommst du auch zum Laufen?“

The comment under your question that says „um... zu“ isn‘t technically wrong either, you could say „kommst du auch um zu laufen?“ but that has a different meaning. „Kommst du auch zum Laufen“ most likely asks „will you be there to run?“ while „kommst du auch um zu laufen?“ kind of implies that you already committed to coming there, and asks if you intent to run, too. „Zum“ means „to“ like to the cinema, to the mall, to the sports event... while „um ... zu“ means „to“ like in „in order to“. „i‘ve came to this place to run an errand“ uses the word „to“ 2 times, the first means „zum (Ort)“ and the  second „um... (etwas) zu (tun)“.